# syntax: create table 'variable'

Tags: php, mysqli

there are a lot of ways to work with variable in this area, but this place of the variable seems to work with the syntax I wrote beneath. Except, it doesn't.

```
$name = (string)$_GET['name']; 


mysqli_select_db($con,"dbtest");

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE '".$name."' (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: btw; did you even connect and query/execute that?

Comment: use `\`` instead of `'` for table name.

Comment: and looking at what you're trying to do here; sounds unsafe and no password field created long enough to hold a safe hash. So, you're just going to allow someone to register with an email address? What do you think will happen when someone "guesses" it/them?

Comment: Good night, there's a lot to say here.  Not sure it's an exact duplicate either?  Certainly we should be mentioning the use of filter_input with an entire slew of extra flags after FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
(get rid of quotes and double quotes around your variable -> name)

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $name (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Comment: what do you think will happen if their table is called `my table 1-1` or [`CALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) or `my-table` or `123`? think about it ;-)

Comment: very clever, I got that covered;) but you way worked.thanks